# Are these two while loops equivalent?

Tags: c++, loops

I have two snippets:

```
  while (indent-- > 0)
  {
    out << "  ";
  }
```

```
  while (indent > 0)
  {
    indent -= 1;
    out << "  ";
  }
```

As far as I can see, there isn't any undefined behaviour going on in the first snippet (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)).

My question is: are these two snippets equivalent?

I am not so sure, because the `-=` operator has a higher precedence than the compare operator, and should therefore be performed first in the first snippet. The second snippet however, only performs this after comparison.

Comment: precedence is irrelevant in both snippets. The only statement with more than one operator is `indent-- > 0` and there is no ambivalence. `(indent--) > 0` is the only way to parse it, `indent-- (> 0)` or `indent (-- > 0)` are not valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They will run the body of the loop the same number of times, but they are not the same.

The first will decrement `indent` one extra time, leaving `indent` at `-1`, because the `--` operator will run whether the condition succeeds or fails.

The second will leave `indent` at `0`.  Here's a complete working example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   int indent = 3;
   while (indent-- > 0)
   {
      std::cout << "First ";  // Prints three times
   }

   std::cout << indent << std::endl;  // Prints -1

   indent = 3;
   while (indent > 0)
   {
      indent -= 1;
      std::cout << "Second ";  // Prints three times
   }

   std::cout << indent << std::endl;  // Prints 0
}

// Output:
// First First First -1
// Second Second Second 0
```

Comment: There is an additional difference (assuming that `indent` is a signed integral type): if `indent` has the value `INT_MIN` (or the minimum corresponding to the type) before getting to the loop, then the first snippet has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4):

There's no difference between the two because `indent--` is a post-increment - it will return the previous value of `indent` - there would be a difference for `while (--indent > 0)` though.

So, for basic types, they're equivalent.

Since this is C++, though, you can just as well define your own class, have `indent` an object of that type, overload `--` and `=(int)` and `>` and have them behave completely different (I hope this isn't the case).

EDIT: correct, the value of `indent` isn't the same.

Comment: No, this is part of some old code that I am reviewing/documenting :P
I just want to make it more obvious what the code is actually doing

Comment: You are one sec early.. deleted my answer.. But please read Pihhan's answer, there is difference between both codes..

Comment: However the value of `indent` after the loop will be different for the two snippets.

Answer (score 3):

I think they are different. What is missing is initialization of indent and its type.

First loop will always decrement after comparison, second only when condition was true. If (indent > 0) is true before loop, they behave exactly the same way. If indent==0 however, first loop will make it -1 without printing it once. Second will not print any indent, but wont decrease indent also.

So, they are different in some cases.

Comment: This statement is not correct: "If (indent > 0) is true before loop, they behave exactly the same way."  The first snippet will always decrement `indent` one more time than the second snippet.